# Chromium 32.0.1700.107 Ubuntu 12.04, sqlite3 database?

Tags: chromium

In Chromium 32.0.1700.107 Ubuntu 12.04, I can't locate the directory in sqlite3 database? Any one can help me.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu all the Chromium related database are stored under location directory

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/databases
```

You can use 
[SQLite](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlitebrowser) [image: Install sqlitebrowser] database Browser to view the contents of the db

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite databases are located in `~/.config/chromium`.